# How can I increase the number of potions?

Tags: cheats, candy-box

I need help to get more berserk potions, but I cant seem to get the script to work in the development console. How can I get more berserk potions?

Answer (score 3):

In the development console, type the following two lines:

```
potions.setPotionNbrOwned(potions.list.berserk, 20);
potions.updateOnPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

add more candies and/or lollipops to the mixture