# How do I enter cheats using the Javascript / Developer console?

Tags: cheats, candy-box

I _really_ love candies. I also would like to be able to afford everything in the game and eat as much candies as possible to increase my hitpoints/health.

I've heard that I can enter various cheats in this game using the Javascript / Developer console. How do I do this?

---

> Related: [Will using Javascript sorcery have a negative effect on the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116136/4797)

Comment: Patience is a virtue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access the Developper's Computer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116312/how-do-i-access-the-developpers-computer)

Comment: @Anto This is not a duplicate of that question

Comment: @Anto This question is about entering Javascript commands (cheats) into the browser. That [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116312/4797) is about an unrelated game mechanic (there is actually a "Developper's Computer" in the game).

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, open up the Javascript / Developer console of your browser:

#### Chrome:

1. Press either <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open the "Console" tab of the **Developer Tools**.

Alternative method:

1. Press either <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the **Developer Tools**.
2. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> (or click on "Show console" in the bottom right corner) to slide the console up.

*Note: In Chrome's dev tools, there is a "Console" tab. However, a smaller "slide-up" console can be opened while any of the other tabs is active.*

---

#### Safari:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open the **Web Inspector**.
2. See Chrome's step 2. (Chrome and Safari have pretty much identical dev tools.)

*Note: Step 1 only works if the "Show Develop menu in menu bar" check box in the Advanced tab of the Preferences menu is checked!*

---

#### Internet Explorer 9:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer tools. 2. Click the "Console" tab.

---

#### Firefox:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to open the **Web console**.

or, if [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) is installed (recommended):
1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open **Firebug**.
2. Click on the "Console" tab.

---

#### Opera:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open **Dragonfly**. 2. Click on the "Console" tab.

---

Then, type or paste the cheat code you want to enter. e.g. Enter `candies.setNbrOwned(x)`, where `x` is the amount of candies you want. This will set the amount of candies you have (note that your candy per second rate will stay as it were before). Be careful not to eat too much candy as you might have [issues solving a particular part of the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116136/4797).

Questions related to Candy box! cheats:

- [How can I increase the number of potions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116206/4797)
- [How do I lower my hitpoints?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116265/4797)
- [How do I change the candy per second rate in the JavaScript console?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116367/4797)

More cheats at the ["Cheats" article of the Candy Box Wiki](http://candybox.wikia.com/wiki/Cheats)

---

<sup>Javascript / Developer console opening instructions from: [Webmasters Stack Exchange post, "How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525/27742)</sup>

Comment: But how do you actually edit the code after your in the javascript console? It doesn't let me type anthing

Comment: @JoeCurtis What browser are you using? Try clicking on the text input area (blinking "|" [without the quotes] symbol). The console's text input should normally be editable. If you've already pressed 'Enter', then that means the command had already been processed or executed and is not editable anymore. Just enter another command again to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

To enter cheat codes in Candy-Box simply do the following:

1. Go to the javascript console of any browser
2. Enter commands like:

   - `candies.setnbrOwned = <Amt of candies>`
   - `candies.setcandiesPerSecond = <Amt of candies>`